# Python: String index out or range in while loop while i try to covert a string into a list

Tags: python, string, list, while-loop, stringindexoutofbounds

I am trying to convert a string consisting of numbers separated by a hyphen ('-') into a list that contains only the numbers. For example:- if a string **str="10-2-517-92"** then the output should be: 
**n=[10,2,517,92]**.
I have written this code so far:

```
a="10-2-517-92"
n=[]
i=0
while(i<len(a)):
        m=0
        if(a[i]!="-"):
            while(a[i]!="-" and i<len(a)):
                m=m*10
                m=m+int(a[i])
                i+=1
            n.append(m)
            i=i+1
print(n)
```

I am getting an error message: **string index out of range** (at the second while loop I have used)

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Hi - not a solution, but a suggestion - get lot's of "print" statements in there ... find out what the string is and what the index is when that error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any constraints why you don't just use the `split` method?

```
a="10-2-517-92"

arr_of_numbers = a.split('-')

# -> ['10', '2', '517', '92']
```

**doc**:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: didn't know about the split method. Thanks alot. It made it very simple.

Comment: @SachinSharma Happy it helped. Could you please accept the answer and upvote? :) thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use str split method instead.

```py
n=a.split('-')
```

or you can use regex split

```py
import re

re.split(patern, a)
```

Comment: how is your answer any different?

Comment: I also added the regex split

Answer (score 0):

The error happens at the while loop when the value of `i=11`. And this is expected since the max index of your `a` variable is only `10`.

Your code is correct except you just need to change from this

```
while(a[i]!="-" and i<len(a)):
```

to this to correctly make use of a [logical operator](https://opentechschool.github.io/python-beginners/en/logical_operators.html)

```
while(i<len(a) and a[i]!="-"):
```

This way you will be using the logical `and` operator, meaning that if the first condition is false then the second condition will not be run. This, therefore, deters from checking index elements when it's greater than the length.

This outputs

```
[10, 2, 517, 92]
```

Comment: If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do not address your question "why do you get a index error".

The reason is that you check `a[i] != "-"` before checking `i < len(a)`, so when you reach the end you explode before you see if it is safe.

If you switch the order you get your result correctly `[10, 2, 517, 92]`.

That being said:

- you should use split unless this is a homework assignment.
- you don't need to convert each char to int one by one, `int('517')` also works if you want to group by string instead of doing the `*10` stuff.